# Meteor: How to implement text search on a collection along with other find queries in Meteor?

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I have an app and users can create their own private Notes.

I am trying to implement a search function for these notes.

Notes are stored in a collection with Schema:

```
note = 
  threadId: params.threadId
  date: date
  userId: user._id,
  html: params.html
```

In my router (using iron-router) I use the data function to return users note data to the page:

```
Notes.find({threadId: @params._id})
```

Then in jade I iterate over the note and show them

```
 each notes
   +note
```

But Now I want to include a search function so the user can search their own notes.

I want to search the html field of each Note. But I want to also filter the Notes by threadId field.

Basically something like this

```
Notes.find({threadId: @params._id}).search('test', field: {html: true})
```

Which finds all notes with the specific threadId field, and then searches the html field of those notes with the query term 'test'

And then once I find them, how do I update the page with the new data?

--------------------------------------UPDATE -----------------------------------------

So I got searching working, but I loose reactivity on the notes. Which is kind of a bummer. I am looking for a better way to do this.

```
 notes = Notes.find({threadId: @researchThread._id}, {sort: {date: -1}})
 $('#notes-container').empty()

 notes.forEach (note) ->
   if note.html.indexOf("philosophy") > -1
     renderedTemplate = UI.renderWithData Template.note, note
     UI.insert renderedTemplate, $('#notes-container')[0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regular expression ([$regex](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/)) in your selector

```
notes = Notes.find({
                       threadId: @researchThread._id, 
                        html: {$regex: 'philosophy'}
                   }, 
                   {
                       sort: {date: -1}
                   })
```

#### Update

To make it reactive, you need [Deps.autorun](http://docs.meteor.com/#deps_autorun)

```
Deps.autorun ->

    notes = Notes.find({
                       threadId: @researchThread._id, 
                        html: {$regex: 'philosophy'}
                   }, 
                   {
                       sort: {date: -1}
                   })

    /* Put your render things here */
```

#### Update

The api is changed, used `Tracker.autorun` instead

Comment: that works pretty well, thanks. But I am still having trouble with reactivity. Once I get the cursor data, how can I update the page so it is still reactive? I tried using UI.renderWithData and the UI.insert each note like in the updated example but I loose reactivity....

Comment: You need `Deps.autorun`